# Cannot get cookies in wp7 using HttpWebRequest

Tags: windows-phone-7, cookies, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to save cookies in a post request. Here is my code :

```
        CookieContainer myCookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = userAgent;
        myHttpWebRequest.CookieContainer = myCookieContainer;
        myHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        byte[] postdata = encoding.GetBytes(submitString);

        myHttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(async1 =>
        {
            using (Stream stream = myHttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(async1))
                stream.Write(postdata, 0, postdata.Length);
            myHttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(async2 =>
            {
                HttpWebResponse rep = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(async2);
                CookieCollection cookies = rep.Cookies;
                using (Stream stream = rep.GetResponseStream())
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    String content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    if (pageDownloadedEventHandler != null)
                        pageDownloadedEventHandler(content);
                }
            }, null);
        }, null);
```

Alaways the CookieContainer is empty.
How to get the cookies?

Comment: You're sending a request without cookies, are you sure the server is actually setting any cookies to pass back?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes, i see the cookies in wireshark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be perfect, if the server sends you back any cookies you should see them in rep.Cookies, as well as in myCookieContainer.

If you want to be sure use Fiddler or Wireshark to analyze the HTTP network traffic and look for the cookies, but if I'm right you won't find them. In this case my idea is to analyze the network traffic doing the same request with your browser, maybe the php/asp.net/other app decided not to set cookies due to some missing request headers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I use wireshark and find out the server did return cookies. I find out that the process for the site has to be twice confirm, and what i did is passing a null pageDownloadedEventHandler the second time. After i changed it to a real handler, the cookies appeared. Is it because the async code won't sync the cookies in cookieContainer?

Comment: The cookie container is synced in case of async request too. Probably because you didn't specify a downloaded event handler, the library assumed you don't need any of the response data, so it didn't recieve any of them.