# Getting Cookies from HTTP response

Tags: windows-phone-7, cookies, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, response

I have problem getting cookies from HTTP response. Im sure, that response should have cookies, but I cant see them in my app.

Here is my code:

```cs
    private static CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
    private static CookieContainer Cookies
    {
        get
        {
            return cookies;
        }
    }

    public static async Task<HttpStatusCode> SendPostRequest(string url, string postData)
    {
        if (url == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("url");

        if (postData == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("postData");

        HttpStatusCode statusCodeToReturn = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        var cookies = Cookies;
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
        //webRequest.SupportsCookieContainer = true;
        using (var requestStream = await webRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        using (WebResponse response = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            statusCodeToReturn = WebResponseToHTTPStatusCode(response);
        }

        return statusCodeToReturn;
    }
```

Cookies (using Wireshark):

```
rack.session=BAh7BkkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiJFMzg1ZjYxNzIzNzQ4MmY5NmI3NTMw%0AYWMwZmRjNmVmZjMwMDk4OTgzZGUwNjRlNzIzODlmODNjYzE2YmVmMjNlOQ%3D%3D%0A--30d79cd2276c3236de11104852bba4b84bf80f26; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Comment: possible duplicate [WP7 Cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622296/cannot-get-cookies-in-wp7-using-httpwebrequest)

Comment: I got it. The problem is in returned Cookies. Cookies without set DOMAIN are NOT supported in WP7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in returned Cookies. Cookies without set DOMAIN are NOT supported in WP7.

Comment: So Is there chance how to get them at all? For example using WebBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just create an global variable to save the cookie.Such as in your app.xaml.cs file you can create a variable like this:

```
public CookieContainer GlobalCookie{get;set;}
```

And make the GloalCookie equal to your successful HttpWebRequest CookieContainer.

Then you can use this variable when you call another API.Hope to help you:)

Comment: I have global variable. See my code in post. (private static CookieContainer Cookies).

Comment: I wonder when you give the global static cookies variable value?I can't see it in your above code segment.

Comment: See my first post (question). First 8 rows of code. Anyway I solved it.