# Cannot get cookies from HttpWebResponse on Windows Phone 7

Tags: cookies, asynchronous, windows-phone, httpwebresponse

I am thoroughly confused as to what is the problem here. My understanding of the `CookieContainer` must be totally wrong. I am trying to log in to a website hosted on my machine. I have fiddler set up as a proxy, so I am able to read the traffic.

Every time I try to view the cookies on windows phone, the cookie container is always empty. I have tried so many different things to be able to get that container filled, but everything has failed. This is the last thing I tried:

```
        CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://localhost:8888/account/logon");
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.CookieContainer = cc;
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(streamResult =>
        {
            HttpWebRequest xR = streamResult.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
            Stream stream = xR.EndGetRequestStream(streamResult);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
            sw.Write("username=user1&password=1111");
            sw.Close();

            xR.BeginGetResponse(responseResult =>
            {
                HttpWebRequest yR = responseResult.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
                HttpWebResponse response = yR.EndGetResponse(responseResult) as HttpWebResponse;
                response.Close();

                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("cc count: " + cc.Count.ToString() + "\nresponse count: " + response.Cookies.Count));
            }, xR);

        }, request);
```

However, if I use the exact same code in a console app, the container "cc" has the cookies!

```
        CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://localhost:8888/account/logon");
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.CookieContainer = cc;
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(streamResul =>
        {
            HttpWebRequest xR = streamResul.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
            Stream stream = xR.EndGetRequestStream(streamResul);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
            sw.Write("username=user1&password=1111");
            sw.Close();

            xR.BeginGetResponse(responseResult =>
            {
                HttpWebRequest yR = responseResult.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
                HttpWebResponse response = yR.EndGetResponse(responseResult) as HttpWebResponse;
                response.Close();

                Console.WriteLine("cc count: {0}\nresponse count: {1}", cc.Count.ToString(), response.Cookies.Count);
            }, xR);

        }, request);

        Console.Read();
```

The server is sending back both cookies that I am looking for each time I test it. However for whatever reason, the windows phone code does not get those cookies. This is pretty much the same as this question: [Cannot get cookies in wp7 using HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622296/cannot-get-cookies-in-wp7-using-httpwebrequest) however I don't understand what the solution was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I feel like a fool. It has been working all along... Maybe to others this is obvious, but I missed it. The problem is that since the cookies that are being sent back are `HttpOnly`, the cookie container does not expose them at all, even if you ask for the count of cookies.

It is strange though that in the console version, I can see that there are two, but I suppose the System.Net.dll for windows phone locked down the `CookieContainer` a little more.

Comment: Can u please tell me how to get cookies from a url in windows phone??